# MySQL how to select all rows by specific day (mon, tue, etc) with datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I have an event system setup where a user can add an event for say Monday and it can either occur once or it can be a reoccurring event. So in my application whenever the users requests to see all events for Monday I want to return any events that are on that day and also return any reoccurring events that are on Monday but could have been added in the past.

I'm not sure how the MySQL query should look. In the database I have these fields for the event.

`id`, `title`, `day (DATETIME)`, `reoccurring (TINYINT) 0/1`

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: `where day = myday OR (DAYNAME(day) = DAYNAME(myday) AND reoccur = 1)`

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DAYNAME()` function in your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE day = currentDay
OR (
    DAYNAME(day) = DAYNAME(currentDay)
    AND reoccuring = 1
)
```

For more examples of DAYNAME:
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayname-function.php